# How create a custom numeric pad for iOS?

Tags: ios, numeric, custom-keyboard

I Created a keyboard extension like this:

[image]

But I don't know where to define my custom keyboard to be a numeric pad.
If any number type textfield tapped by user, the iOS default numeric pad will present with no switch button to my custom numeric pad.

The question is:

**How to define my custom keyboard to be a numeric pad?**

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's docs [Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html):

> Your custom keyboard is also ineligible to type into so-called phone pad objects, such as the phone number fields in Contacts. These input objects are exclusively for strings built from a small set of alphanumeric characters specified by telecommunications carriers and are identified by having one or another of the following two keyboard type traits:
>
> - UIKeyboardTypePhonePad
> - UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad
>
> When a user taps in a phone pad object, the system temporarily replaces your keyboard with the appropriate, standard system keyboard. When the user then taps in a different input object that requests a standard keyboard via its type trait, your keyboard automatically resumes.

So, it looks like you **cannot** do what you're asking.

Comment: OK Thanks, but how about a decimal or email keyboard?

Comment: From that same doc page: *To present a keyboard layout appropriate to the current text input object, respond to the object’s UIKeyboardType property. For each trait you support, change the contents of your primary view accordingly.*